# Select based on column name list in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a list of column names, for example:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I'd like to build a sqlalchemy ORM query which is equivalent to:

```
q = db.query(Foo.a, Foo.b, Foo.c)
```

Of course I could just use the query:

```
q = db.query(Foo)
```

..., convert each result row to a dict, and extract the values from that using the list of column names from above as keys. I'd rather not do that because I need only a few columns from a large table and I'd like to avoid the overhead.

Comment: How about `q = db.query(*[getattr(Foo, attr) for attr in cols])`?

Comment: Thanks, that's the more elegant one-line version of what I eventually came up with myself.

Answer (score 0):

Same story always: Racked my brain for hours, gave up, asked the question, and found the solution a few minutes later:

```
colspec = [ Foo.__dict__[k] for k in cols ]
q = db.query(*colspec)
```

Answer (score -1):

As said in a comment by @Abdou

```
q = db.query(*[getattr(Foo, attr) for attr in cols])
```

worked for me

Comment: Thanks. However, copy-pasting someone else's answer is not a good idea here on Stack Exchange. As the other answer was provided in the comments (not as an answer), I think you could add more information here on why it works best, provide some documentation links and citations. You should familiarize yourself to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).