# How to query specific columns from an array with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm building a flask application and need an dict from my database model. The query should filter by user_ids and only query a few rows. I guess the best way is to filter the rows and the use the internal `__dict__` object to return my dict. Currently I know how to filter by ids, but I have no idea how to select specific rows. `Users.query.filter(Users.id.in_(user_ids)).all()`

the array of rows looks like
`rows = ["username", "role", "last_seen"]`

any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905714/2681632, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995345/select-based-on-column-name-list-in-sqlalchemy, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102412/dynamically-query-a-subset-of-columns-in-sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[load_only](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#load-only-cols) should do the job:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only
rows = ["username", "role", "last_seen"]
session.query(Users).filter(Users.id.in_(user_ids)).options(load_only(*rows)).all()
```